# Run several java programs from same project folder in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have three java programs that communicate using sockets.  Each program runs separately from the other, but I still want to be able to keep all of them in the same project folder because they communicate.

I tried simply copying over folders that contain the code for each program, and putting them in the source folder, but this does not seem to be working.  I think it may have something to do with putting each program in its own package, allowing them to be independent, yet still in the same folder.

My current setup:

[image]

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have stored 3 projects under the same src directory this cannot work.
Under src should be a package.

You can create 3 sources directories and have each project inside these.
In your project structure, you then define those 3 directories as Sources.

see picture

[image]